# How to use Haskell Ghc API to load the Haskell source code dynamically? When import some third part dependence

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have a small project that generate some source code dependent on command line arguments, and then execute the generated haskell code.

I try to use GHC API `runGhc` to load the source file and execute it. I found some examples , all of source code file do not import third part packages.

But My source code import some packages and it raise `Could not find module` exception.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE CPP               #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiWayIf        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns      #-}



import GHC
import GHC.Paths ( libdir )
import DynFlags

main =
    defaultErrorHandler defaultFatalMessager defaultFlushOut $ do
      runGhc (Just libdir) $ do
        dflags <- getSessionDynFlags
        setSessionDynFlags $ dflags{
          hscTarget = HscInterpreted
          , ghcLink = LinkInMemory

                                   }
        target <- guessTarget "Demo.hs" Nothing
        setTargets [target]
        load LoadAllTargets
```

And my `Demo.hs` is like

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-unused-imports #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-name-shadowing #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-unused-matches #-}


module Demo where
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal as BSL
import qualified Data.Aeson as DA

buildRequestFromJson ::
                       BSL.ByteString -> BSL.ByteString -> Maybe EchoRequest
buildRequestFromJson payload = (DA.decode payload)
```

The error is

```
    Could not find module ‘Data.Aeson’
    Perhaps you meant Data.Version (from base-4.12.0.0)
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
    |
 13 | import qualified Data.Aeson as DA
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I am looking for how to execute the source code. I failed to use `hint`, `plugins` package. And I want to know how to handle it.

Comment: You might be better off using **stack** or **cabal** to ensure that all dependencies are resolved when the generated code is built

Comment: The EchoRequest type do not be showed in the code . But I think this will make no different. I have add `aeson` package dependent in cabal and stack file already.

Comment: I raised a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51064855/use-dependencies-in-hint-when-installing) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/ac3ajk/is_it_possible_for_a_haskell_application_to_have/ed6m7j2/). (Also see gelisam's response to the latter.)

Comment: I glance over the hint source code , it also use the ghc api. I think it will call a new ghc instance. The two instance have independent env. Hint can not know how to load the third part deps from disk.